# Proving a sum diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I show that if $\sum\limits_{m=k}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda_m}$ diverges then $\sum\limits_{m=k}^\infty \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\lambda_m} \right)$ diverges? I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Do you have any other conditions of the $\lambda_m$?

Comment: Sorry, yes $\lambda_m > 0$ for all $m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe that

$$
\sum_{m=k}^\infty \log \left(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_m}\right)
    = \log \prod_{m=k}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_m}\right)
    \geq \log \left(1+\sum_{m=k}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda_m} \right) = \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

for $x \geq 0,$ $x \leq 1,$
$$ x - \frac{x^2}{2} \leq \log (1+x) \leq x  $$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_n}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{\lambda_n}} = 1$

Comment: Why is this true? What if $\lambda_n=1$ for all $n$? Then $\sum\limits_{m=k}^\infty 1$ diverges but the limit above is $log2$

Comment: We can assume that $\dfrac{1}{\lambda_n} \to 0, n \to \infty$. Like taking $\lambda_n = n$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why we can assume that

Comment: @NotALoner Why would you assume that?

Answer (score 0):

$$\log\left(1+\frac 1 {\lambda_m}\right) \ge \frac 1 {2\lambda_m}.$$